# Putting nullable values into tableadapters - is there a better way?

Tags: c#, nullable, tableadapter

I find myself doing things like the following a lot:

```
if (groupid.HasValue)
{
    row.GroupId = group.Value;
}
else
{
    row.SetGroupIdNull();
}
```

Is there a nicer way to do this (with overloading or such) so that I don't end up repeating this a few hundred times throughout my project?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
row.GroupId = groupid.HasValue ? group.Value : null;
```

Or better yet like this:

```
row.SetGroupId(group);
```

where SetGroupId can be defined as an extension method for your Row class (if you don't have access to it):

```
public void SetGroupId(Group group){
   if (groupid.HasValue)
   {
       row.GroupId = group.Value;
   }
   else
   {
       row.SetGroupIdNull();
   }
}
```

What does `SetGroupIdNull()` method do?

Answer (score 0):

You'll still have to edit everywhere, but the following code is slightly cleaner:

```
row.GroupId = groupid ?? [what ever SetGroupIdNull() does];
```

though if `row.GroupId` is nullable you should be able to just do:

```
row.GroupId = groupid;
```